How to debug errors in Gulp?
I'm on a project that is using Gulp to compile and run tasks. I'm facing an error with the gulp-file-include plugin that will throw this error in console PluginError: Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 287, this will cause that the project build will fail.
Since there is no indication about the file that is causing the error or the property name that miss the double quote, I'm unable to find the problem. Is there any way to know exactly where is the error?
I've tried using gulp-plumber, the project will build but the included files are not processed due to the error. How I can debug the problem correctly?
